# print correct dates in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am putting the entire code here. I want to print out different information as shown in my code for each different date(day) of the year. I have been trying different PHP functions since the first day I asked my question, but I seem not to get the answer. Every other day of the week works fine, but the weekends(sat or sun) has been the headache. Printing the correct date on weekends is the question that needs answers from better programmers, please.(For example let's take this week and next week weekends, I should have the following prints: Happy Weekend, today is **Saturday 2019-02-09**. And on the next day which is a Sunday, I should print out: Happy Weekend, today is **Sunday 2019-02-10**. Also next week weekend should give 2019-02-16 and 2019-02-17 respectively on the differnt days of the weekend, but this is not happening. I have been on this for almost 1month before even posting my question here 2weeks ago. Help a brother.

```
    $date = new DateTime('');   
      $datei = $date->format('Y-m-d');  
      $newYear = new DateTime('');
      $newYear_date = $newYear->format('2019-01-01');
      $ValentineS = new DateTime('');
      $valentineS_date = $ValentineS->format('2019-02-14');
      $WomenDay = new DateTime('');
      $WomenDay_date = $WomenDay->format('2019-03-08');
      /* ...other days not shown for brevity..*/
      /*...move to the weekends....*/
      $sat_begin = new DateTime('2019-01-21');
      $sat_end = new DateTime('2019-12-30');
      $sat_end = $sat_end->modify('+4 day');
      $sat_interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
      $sat_daterange = new DatePeriod($sat_begin, $sat_interval, $sat_end);
      $sun_begin = new DateTime('2019-01-22');
      $sun_end = new DateTime('2019-12-31');
      $sun_end = $sun_end->modify('+4 day');
      $sun_interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
      $sun_daterange = new DatePeriod($sun_begin, $sun_interval, $sun_end);
   foreach ($sat_daterange as $sat_date){

      $saturday = date('w', strtotime($sat_date->format('Y-m-d')));
        if ($saturday == 6 && $datei == $sat_date) {
      } 
  }foreach ($sun_daterange as $sun_date) {
     $sunday = date('w', strtotime($sun_date->format('Y-m-d')));
       if ($sunday == 0 && $datei == $sun_date) {
       }
     }
    switch ('Y-m-d') {
     case '2019-01-01':
     echo 'HAPPY NEW YEAR today is Tuesday 2019-01-01. A Public Holiday';
      break;
      case '2019-02-14':
      echo "HAPPY VALENTINE'S DAY , today is Thursday 2019-02-14 an observed 
       day, but NOT A PUBLIC HOLIDAY ";
       break;
      case '2019-03-08':
      echo "HAPPY WOMEN'S DAY , today is Friday 2019-03-08 an observed day to 
       recognize women, but NOT A PUBLIC HOLIDAY ";
       break;
       case $sat_date->format('Y-m-d'):
        echo 'HAPPY WEEKEND, today is '.'<b>'.'Saturday '.$sat_date->format("Y-m-d").'</b>'.'<br>' ;
        break;
      case $sun_date->format("Y-m-d"):
        echo 'HAPPY WEEKEND, today is '.'<b>'.'Sunday '.$sun_date->format("Y-m-d").'</b>'.'<br>' ;
        break;  
     default:
      echo "TODAY IS A WORKDAY, have a good day!".'<br>';
      break;
```

Comment: There is no method `diff()` in PHP's `DatePeriod` class, to get the interval, call `getDateInterval()` method, please check the doc here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer the next day, I asked the question on a forum. The answer was short, concise, precise and effective. I thought to share as it will be of help not to only this problem, but varieties of problems by tweaking the code. Credit to ***astonecipher***.

```
<?php
$holidays = [
    "01-01" => "New Years Day",
    "02-14" => "VALENTINE'S DAY, an observed day, but NOT A PUBLIC HOLIDAY",
    "03-08" => "WOMEN'S DAY",
    "12-25" => "Christmas Day",
    ];


$date = new DateTime();
for($index = 0; $index < 356; $index++)
{
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    if(array_key_exists($date->format("m-d"), $holidays))
        echo "Happy {$holidays[$date->format("m-d")]} {$date->format("Y-m-d")}";
    else if($date->format("w") > 0 && $date->format("w") < 6)
        echo "Today is a work day {$date->format("Y-m-d")}";
    else 
        echo "It's the weekend {$date->format("Y-m-d")}";

    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your interval code inside the range for loop:

```
<?php

  $date = new DateTime();   
  $datei = $date->format('Y-m-d');  

  $sat_begin = new DateTime('2019-01-21');  
  $sat_end = new DateTime('2019-12-30');   
  $sat_end = $sat_end->modify('+4 day');  
  $sat_interval = new DateInterval('P1D');  
  $sat_daterange = new DatePeriod($sat_begin, $sat_interval, $sat_end); 

  $sun_begin = new DateTime('2019-01-22');  
  $sun_end = new DateTime('2019-12-31');  
  $sun_end = $sun_end->modify('+4 day');  
  $sun_interval = new DateInterval('P1D');  
  $sun_daterange = new DatePeriod($sun_begin, $sun_interval, $sun_end); 


    foreach ($sat_daterange as $sat_date){  
          $interval = $sat_date->diff($date);  
            $saturday = date('w', strtotime($sat_date->format("Y-m-d")));      

         if ($saturday == 6 || $datei == $sat_date) {

             echo  'Happy Weekend, today is '. '<b>  '.$sat_date->format("Y-m-d").' </b>' . '. We have' .$interval->format(' <b> %a days </b> to the Weekend.')."<br><br>";
          } 
    } 

    foreach ($sun_daterange as $sun_date) {  
          $interval = $sun_date->diff($date);  
          $sunday = date('w', strtotime($sun_date->format("Y-m-d")));  

          if ($sunday == 0 || $datei == $sun_date) {

      echo  'Happy Weekend, today is '. '<b>  '.$sun_date->format("Y-m-d").' </b>' . '. We have' .$interval->format(' <b> %a days </b> to the Weekend.')."<br>";
           }
     }

?>
```

Comment: Yeah @McBern, Your response is appreciated. I was able to print out all dates in one of my tries, but when I tried to print a single date, that is the present day's date, I couldn't. **I want to print only the date on the present day**, not all the dates. That is, if ( $datei == $sat_date) or ( $datei == $sun_date) **I want to print the particular matched Saturday / Sunday's date. Prining one date for each matched day**.

Comment: You can issue a `break;` command right after `echo happy weekend` statement for both saturday and sunday.

Comment: with the break statement, I was able to print out two dates. The two dates in the if condition, but what I want to print is one date. For an example, today's date is Saturday the 26th. I want the code to print:  **Happy Weekend, today is 2019-01-26. We have 0 days to the Weekend**(only), but it is printing:  **Happy Weekend, today is 2019-01-26 . We have 0 days to the Weekend**.(on line 1)  **Happy Weekend, today is 2019-01-27. We have 0 days to the Weekend**.(on line 2). What  I suspect, **$datei** is matching all dates in the condition. I am on it too, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

This is my solution for you:

```
$currentdate = getdate();
if ($currentdate['wday'] == 1) {
$days = 5;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 2) {
$days = 3;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 3) {
$days = 2;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 4) {
$days = 1;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 5) {
$days = 0;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 6) {
$days = 0;
} elseif ($currentdate['wday'] == 0) {
$days = 0;
}

$date = $currentdate['year'].'-'.$currentdate['mon'].'-'.$currentdate['mday'];
$weekenddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + '.$days.' days'));

echo 'Happy Weekend, Today is '.$date.'. We have '.$days.' day(s) to the Weekends';
```

I just tested it, it's 1 day until weekend :P
Have fun I guess?

Comment: your response is appreciated. I want to print the exact number of days for any day of the week compared with the present day's date, not a fixed number of day(s), like All Saturdays and Sundays, printing 0 day(s) here.